# What parameter differentiates between emulated device and real android device?

Tags: emulation, device

I am trying to get a unique parameter so that an application can distinguish between a real android device and an emulator.

Comment: Simplify language

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint usually contains "generic" and the PRODUCT usually contains "sdk", you could additionally check for "vbox" in the fingerprint.